# how to convert current Date in 22 july 2022 00:00:00 format using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need the current date in following format at 00:00:00 time.

Like say current date is July 22 2021 Then I need that date along with 00:00:00 time.

Expected Output:

Fri 22 july 2022 00:00:00 IST2021

Answer (score 0):

I guess This will work for you

`console.log(new Date().toString())`

output- `Fri Jul 22 2022 17:03:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess This will work

```
const d = new Date();
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
const months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
let month = months[d.getMonth()];
const zone = String(String(d).split("(")[1]).split(")")[0].replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
const dateTime = dayName +" "+ month+ " "+ d.getDate() + " "+ d.getFullYear()+ " "+ d.getHours() + ":"+ d.getMinutes() +":"+ d.getSeconds()+" "+zone;
console.log(dateTime);
```

output- Fri July 22 2022 17:12:3 PST

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you work with angular you should use pipes to display dates.

```
{{ yourDate | date}} // Jul 22, 2022
```

you can put parameters to have the date format you want

```
{{ yourDate | date:'EE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' }} // Fri, July 22, 2022, 5:17:44 PM
```

Visit https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe for more information.